# How do I conditionally show text field in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, logic, jsx, directory-structure

I have some categories in the folder structure by clicking on one of the folders or files and then clicking on the 'new' button. I need to add a text field below that in a tree structure. How can I achieve this?

[image]

In the above, I have a new button on the top right corner; selecting 'manufacturing' and clicking on the 'new' button text field should be added as shown in the image.

Comment: You should post your component code

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this code below

```js
import {useEffect,useStatus} from 'react'
const Index = ()=>{
  const [type, setType] = useStatus(null)
  
  return <form>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="type1" onChange={()=>setType('type1')} />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="type2" onChange={()=>setType('type2')}/>
    <br />
    {type=='type1' && <input type="text" name="type1input" />}
    {type=='type2' && <input type="text" name="type1input" />}
  </form>
}

export default Index;
```